# hector_slam_launch

Tags: slam, navigation, transform, hector-slam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I can't clearly understand how to set up a launch file with the base_frame or odom. I get the same error /map doesnt exist.

My purpose is to use the hector_slam (ie hector_mapping) in order to do for the time being the same process as we can see on the video in the hector_slam wiki page. I am only using a hokuyo no imu and no odom. Can someone help me to write the launch file ?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37526/hector_slam_launch/) by [sjigi123](https://answers.ros.org/users/2732/sjigi123/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2012-06-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

did you read http://www.ros.org/wiki/hector_slam/Tutorials/SettingUpForYourRobot ?

you have to follow the instructions under 2 (Use without odom frame). I.e. set both base_frame and odom_frame to your hokuyo/robot frame in the launch file. As a starting point maybe take a look at the given launch files in hector_mapping/launch (if i remember correctly).

maybe try that, and if it still does not work do "rosrun tf view_frames" and check if hector mapping publishes a transform from /map to /yourRobotFrame

---

Originally posted by [jodafo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1732/jodafo/) with karma: 365 on 2012-07-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1